# Our company is based in the UK. We have users who are located in the USA, are these users protected by GDPR?

Tags: gdpr

Our company is based in the UK. We have users who are located in the USA, are these users protected by GDPR?

Any help on this questions would be much appreciated!

Comment: From a non-legal, purely practical perspective, since you have to implement GDPR rules anyway for *some* customers, why spend the extra money and make exceptions. The most cost effective way to handle it is to grant them to everybody and be done with it.

Comment: Don't forget you also need to comply with CCPA for California residents

Comment: @NicolasFormichella also this year CPRA (update of CCPA), VCDPA (Virginia),CPA (Colorado), UCPA (Utah), CTDPA (Connecticut)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Yes

When personal data is processed in the context of an EU/EEA/UK establishment (for example, by a company with offices in the UK), then all these processing activities must fully comply with the GDPR, regardless of where the data subjects are located.

For the [UK GDPR](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/eur/2016/679/article/3):

> This Regulation applies to the processing of personal data in the context of the activities of an establishment of a controller or a processor in the United Kingdom, regardless of whether the processing takes place in the United Kingdom or not.

For the [EU GDPR](https://commission.europa.eu/law/law-topic/data-protection/reform/rules-business-and-organisations/application-regulation/who-does-data-protection-law-apply_en#:%7E:text=Answer-,Answer,the%20data%20is%20processed%3B%20or):

> The GDPR applies to:
>
> 1. a company or entity which processes personal data as part of the activities of one of its branches established in the EU, regardless of where the data is processed; or
>
> …